# Selecionar métodos do model no método index do controller Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um método index que busca todos os eventos no banco e mostra em uma tabela

`Model Event:`

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 
        'description', 
        'start_datetime',
        'end_datetime',
    ];

    public function getTodayEvents()
    {

    }

    public function getFiveDaysEvents()
    {

    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/profile', 'Auth\UserController@profile')->name('profile');
Route::post('/profile', 'Auth\UserController@updateProfile')->name('updateProfile');

Route::get('event/index/{filter}', 'EventController@index')->name('indexEvent');
Route::get('event/create', 'EventController@create')->name('createEvent');
Route::post('event/store', 'EventController@store')->name('storeEvent');
Route::get('event/show/{id}', 'EventController@show')->name('showEvent');
Route::get('event/edit/{id}', 'EventController@edit')->name('editEvent');
Route::post('event/update/{id}', 'EventController@update')->name('updateEvent');
Route::get('event/destroy/{id}', 'EventController@destroy')->name('destroyEvent');

});
```

EventController:`

```
public function index()
{
    $events = Event::all();
    return view('event.index')->with('events', $events);
}
```

Nessa tabela que exibe os eventos tenho um menu dropdown para exibir todos os eventos, os eventos de hoje e os eventos dos próximos 5 dias

`View index:`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Eventos')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Eventos</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('createEvent') }}" role="button">Novo Evento</a>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Filtrar <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="{{ route('indexEvent', ['filter' => 'all']) }}">Todos os eventos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ route('indexEvent', ['filter' => 'today']) }}">Eventos de hoje</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ route('indexEvent', ['filter' => 'five']) }}">Eventos nos próximos 5 dias</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Detalhes</th>
            <th>Alterar</th>
            <th>Excluir</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($events as $event)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $event->title }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('showEvent', $event->id) }}" class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></a> 
            </td>         
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('editEvent', $event->id) }}" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('destroyEvent', $event->id) }}" class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Até ai tudo certo, a minha dúvida é que tenho os dois métodos `getTodayEvents()` e `getFiveDaysEvents()` e gostaria de saber como poderia selecionar o método que quero a partir do link na `view` e utilizar somente um método `index` no EventController ao invés de criar ***3 métodos*** `index` cada um com um método do `model` `Event`?

Comment: Passe como parâmetro na URL um valor que identificará quais serão os resultados desejados. Veja na documentação da função [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route)

Comment: Eu até passei route('indexEvent', ['typel' => 'all']) mas e o restante? No método index? Se souber e puder postar uma resposta.

Comment: No método `index` você trata esse valor, com um `switch/case`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se pode utilizar o seguinte, na sua `index` coloque um parâmetro com um valor ***padrão***, exemplo:

```
public function index($filter = null)
{
    if (is_null($filter))
    {
        $events = Event::all();
    }
    else
    {
        $events = Event::where('campo_filtro', $filter)->get();
    }
    return view('event.index')->with('events', $events);
}
```

seria a forma ideal e muito utilizado por desenvolvedores `PHP`. Além disso se pode trabalhar com [scope local](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes) do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) em vez de criar métodos da forma da sua pergunta, por exemplo:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 
        'description', 
        'start_datetime',
        'end_datetime',
    ];

    public function scopeGetEvents($query, $filter)
    {            
        if ($filter == 'today')
        {
            return $query->getEventsToday($query);
        }
        if ($filter == 'five')
        {
            return $query->getEventsFive($query);
        }
        return $query;
    }
    public function scopeGetEventsToday($query)
    {
         return $query-> //... code;
    }
    public function scopeGetEventsFive($query)
    {
         return $query-> //... code;
    }
}
```

e utilizar assim no seu `controller` método `index`

```
public function index($filter = null)
{
    $events = Event::getEvents($filter)->get();
    return view('event.index')->with('events', $events);
}
```

<sub>**Observação:** **campo_filtro** é o campo que você deseja filtrar, e a variável `$filter` seria o valor correspondente. Isso é um exemplo que encaixa de uma maneira geral no seu código, já visto que as informações são poucas.</sub>

A rota ***exemplo***:

```
Route::get('event/index/{filter?}', ['as' => 'indexEvent', 
                                     'uses' => 'EventController@index']);
```

e no ***link***:

```
<li>
   <a href="{{ route('indexEvent', ['all']) }}">Todos os eventos</a>
```

<sub>*Referencias:*</sub>

- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)
- [Scope Local](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes)
- [Valores padrão de argumentos](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Comment: E na view deixo da forma que esta so passando o parametro filter?

Comment: Na view coloquei dessa forma <li><a href="{{ route('indexEvent', ['filter' => 'all']) }}">Todos os eventos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('indexEvent', ['filter' => 'today']) }}">Eventos de hoje</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('indexEvent', ['filter' => 'five']) }}">Eventos nos próximos 5 dias</a></li> e na rota Route::get('event/index/{filter}', 'EventController@index')->name('indexEvent'); mas creio que estou fazendo algo errado.

Comment: Vou colocar a view completa.

Comment: Qual a diferença de Route::get('event/index/{filter?}', ['as' => 'indexEvent', 'uses' => 'EventController@index']); para Route::get('event/index/{filter?}', 'EventController@index');

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63765/discussion-between-marcelo-and-virgilio-novic).