# Como ignorar o $with predefinido do Model no Laravel (ORM Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um Model com *with* já predefinido chamando alguns outros Models.

```
public $with = ["itens", "filial", "cliente", "status", "produtos", "servicos",
  "composicoes", "execucoes", "tipo", "vendedor", "locacoes"];
```

quero ignorar o objeto *"produtos"*, como consigo fazer isto?

Comment: E ai o que achou da solução.

Answer (score 1):

Desenvolva um [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#deleting-models) ***para remover da relação adiantada*** o item ou itens:

```
public function scopeNoEagerLoadsExcept($query, array $items)
{
    if (count($items) == 0)
    {
        return $query;
    }

    $eagerLoads = $this->getEagerLoads();
    $keysEagerLoads = array_keys($eagerLoads);
    $with = array();
    foreach ($keysEagerLoads as $key)
    {
        if (!in_array($key, $items))
        {
            $with[$key] = $eagerLoads[$key];
        }
    }
    $query->setEagerLoads($with);
    return $query;
}
```

nesse método faz uma verificação se o item está dentro da chave das carga adiantada e remove o item nessa [builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) criada, e vale lembrar que após essa materialização de resultado a carga volta a ser como antigamente com todas as relações configuradas que é muito útil para as próximas pesquisas onde precisam de todas as relações.

<sup>***Exemplo de uso:***</sup>

```
 ItemsProduct::noEagerLoadsExcept(['produtos'])->get();
```

<sup>***Leitura***</sup>

- [Para que serve um scope no Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148776/para-que-serve-um-scope-no-laravel)
- [Selecionar métodos do model no método index do controller Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228740/selecionar-m%C3%A9todos-do-model-no-m%C3%A9todo-index-do-controller-laravel)
- [Relacionamento de Relacionamento Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/364463/relacionamento-de-relacionamento-laravel)
- [Disable eager relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052056/disable-eager-relations)

<sup>***Dica***</sup>

Se quiser que esse `model` não carregue as relações configuradas, ou seja, nenhuma relação, utilize o método `setEagerLoads([])`, ***exemplo***:

```
ItemsProduct::setEagerLoads([])->get();
```